# Pandas look for substring then write in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I'm trying to look down a specific column of my csv file for a partial string. If that meets a certain condition, it'll write something else in a different column.

For example:

```
Letter Grade     Percentage
     A        Ninety Five Percent
     C        Seventy Three Percent
     B        Eighty Two Percent
```

The "Percentage" column will always have the same format of "Ninety Five Percent" that is number in words + Percent.

I want to be able to open up a csv file, have python parse the percentage column for the first word such if it contains "Ninety" then it'll assign "A" in the letter grade column, if it contains "Eighty" then B in the letter grade and so on and so forth.

This is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', dtype=str))

A = 'Ninety'
B = 'Eighty'
C = 'Seventy'
D = 'Sixty'

if df[df['Percentage'].isin(A)]:
     df['Letter Grade'] = df['Letter Grade'].str.replace['', 'A', regex=False]
elif df[df['Percentage'].isin(B)]:
     df['Letter Grade'] = df['Letter Grade'].str.replace['', 'B', regex=False]
elif df[df['Percentage'].isin(C)]:
     df['Letter Grade'] = df['Letter Grade'].str.replace['', 'C', regex=False]
elif df[df['Percentage'].isin(D)]:
     df['Letter Grade'] = df['Letter Grade'].str.replace['', 'D', regex=False]
else:
     df['Letter Grade'] = df['Letter Grade'].str.replace['', 'F', regex=False]


df.to_csv(r'file.csv', index=False)
```

It is currently giving me this error: `The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np

df["Letter Grade"] = np.select([df["Percentage"].str.contains(A),
                                df["Percentage"].str.contains(B), 
                                df["Percentage"].str.contains(C),
                                df["Percentage"].str.contains(D)], 
                               ["A","B","C","D"])
```

Alternatively with `findall` and `map`:

```
mapper = {"Ninety": "A", "Eighty": "B", "Seventy": "C", "Sixty": "D"}
df["Letter Grade"] = df["Percentage"].str.findall("|".join(mapper.keys())).str[0].map(mapper)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dictionary` with `split` and `map` function to do that

```
grades={'Ninety':'A', 'Eighty':'B', 'Seventy':'C', 'Sixty':'D'}

df['Letter Grade'] = df.Percentage.str.split(expand=True)[0].map(grades)
```

Comment: if this is your solution then accept it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

@not_speshal's answer is great, but it doesn't actually explain the precise issue that you're having.

`isin` actually returns a dataframe listing each column and whether or not the string was found as a whole item (e.g., it will find `'Ninenty'` but not 'Ninenty x').

Instead, you can use `.str.contains(...)` on the column, which will return a copy of the column where each item is `True` if the string in the columns contained your string, `False` other wise. Then you can call `.any()` on the resulting series which will return `True` if a single item in the series is `True`, and it will return `False` if there are no `True` values in the series (there were no strings that matched).

Instead of

```py
if df[df['Percentage'].isin(A)]:
```

you want:

```py
if df['Percentage'].str.contains('Ninety').any():
```